# Two different limits in one mysql query is possible? (multi array result)

Tags: php, mysql

### My table

```
id Category Name
1  Sports   name1
2  Food     name2
3  Sports   name3
4  Social   name4
5  TV       name5
6  Food     name6
7  Sports   name7
8  TV       name8
```

As you can see each element Name has a Category, at the moment my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM interests ORDER BY category DESC;
```

Then in PHP I'd group by Category and then count the top 3 with their respective names field. I want to do the same but in MySQL (if its possible) because now I have a lot of data and I don't want to query all the table every time, I want to limit the amount of categories to the top 3 and the names to 2.

I tried: `SELECT *,COUNT(*) as catnumber FROM interests GROUP BY category ORDER BY catnumber DESC` LIMIT 5 But just give me the top 5 categories with ONE name element (and I need a maximun of two if they are available). So the result should be something like a multiarray result:

```
Categories = array('Sports' => array('name1', 'name3','name7'), 'Food' => array('name2','name6'), 'TV' => array('name5','name8'))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The last array is the desired result, and the data is the table...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL won't return you a "multiarray" result.

But you can get three categories, with a maximum of two names each, using a query like this:

```
SELECT c.category
     , (SELECT n1.name
          FROM interests n1
         WHERE n1.category = c.catetory
         ORDER BY n1.name
         LIMIT 0,1
       ) AS n1
     , (SELECT n2.name
          FROM interests n2
         WHERE n2.category = c.catetory
         ORDER BY n2.name
         LIMIT 1,1
       ) AS n2
  FROM ( SELECT t.category
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM interests t
          GROUP BY t.category
          ORDER BY cnt DESC
              , t.category
          LIMIT 3
       ) c
```

That should return a result set like this:

```
    category  n1     n2 
    --------  ----   ----
    Sports    name1  name3 
    Food      name2  name6
    TV        name5  name8
```

It's also possible to get the names on separate rows, but the query is a little more complicated:

```
SELECT c.category
     , CASE WHEN i.i = 1 THEN 
       (SELECT n1.name
          FROM interests n1
         WHERE n1.category = c.catetory
         ORDER BY n1.name
         LIMIT 0,1
       ) ELSE
       (SELECT n2.name
          FROM interests n2
         WHERE n2.category = c.catetory
         ORDER BY n2.name
         LIMIT 1,1
       ) END AS `name`
  FROM ( SELECT t.category
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM interests t
          GROUP BY t.category
          ORDER BY cnt DESC
              , t.category
          LIMIT 3
       ) c
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2) i
 ORDER BY c.cnt DESC, t.category, i.i
```

To avoid the return of a NULL value, you can add a HAVING clause before the ORDER BY

```
HAVING n IS NOT NULL
```

That should return:

```
    category  n
    --------  ----
    Sports    name1
    Sports    name3
    Food      name2
    Food      name6
    TV        name5
    TV        name8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP_CONCAT to do this and explode the category on `,`

```
SELECT `category`,
       count(id) AS entries,
       GROUP_CONCAT(NAME)
FROM `interests` l1
GROUP BY `category`
ORDER BY entries DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a multidimensional array directly out of a MySQL query. If I am understanding your table structure and your description of the desired output, you can approximate your array with something like this though:

```
SELECT id,
       Category,
       (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR ',') 
        FROM interests AS sint 
        WHERE sint.Category = interests.Category) as Name,
       (SELECT 
        COUNT(Name) 
        FROM interests AS csint 
        WHERE csint.Category = interests.Category) as count
FROM interests 
GROUP BY Category
HAVING count >= 2
ORDER BY count DESC,CATEGORY
LIMIT 3
```

Which gives you this:

```
id  Category    Name           count
1   Sports    name1,name3,name7     3
2   Food      name2,name6           2
5   TV        name5,name8           2
```

To get the whole table sorted as requested in a comment below, use:

```
SELECT id,
       Category,
       Name,
       (SELECT 
        COUNT(Name) 
        FROM interests AS csint 
        WHERE csint.Category = interests.Category) as count
FROM interests 
ORDER BY count DESC,Category
```

Comment: This works just great!! Thanks!, Im still doing some experiments with the code, can you please help a little more?, how will you query the hole table sorted by the most mention categories? the result should be something like: Sports name1, Sports name3, Sports name7, Food name2, Food name6, and so...

Comment: It looks to like you essentially have that already, but I added a query that will sort as you describe in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT a.category, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(a.NAME)   SEPARATOR ', '),",",2) AS `Top names`
    FROM MyTable AS A JOIN 
        (SELECT category 
        FROM MyTable 
        GROUP BY category 
        ORDER BY count(category) DESC 
        LIMIT 3) AS C
    ON A.category = C.category 
    GROUP BY a.category 
    ORDER BY  count(a.category) DESC, count(A.name)  DESC ;
```

[SQL FIDDLE Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfcc53/1)

Category top size is currently 3 and the top size of names is currently 2. By changing the values you can adjust the size of the top. Be aware that when category and names have a draw the second category or name will not be shown.